# How do I connect a bone to another bone via python script

Tags: python, armature, rigging

I'm trying to make a chain of "segments", meaning I have 3 bones in a setup and I'd like to replicate them along the z-axis. I use a for loop to duplicate the entire armature, my object and then rename the bones of each segment. Which works best for vertex groups assignment.

I then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to join the meshes as well as the armatures. When I go into *Edit Mode* for the mesh, I can just use *Remove Doubles* to connect the pieces, but here is my problem:

When I join the armatures, I have a chain of bones that are not parented, so I was trying to find a method that does something like this:

```
for bone in arm.pose.bones:
  i += 1 
  bone[i].parent = bone[i-1]
```

(pseudocode, but I hope you know what I mean)

But bone parent is read-only and the `ops.pose.parent_set()` only works if there is an active bone, but I could not figure out how to change the active bone. `bone.select` seems to always be `True`, so I'm not entirely sure how to us the ops. I hope there is a better way, like with objects, where you can just assign your parent object/bone.

Answer (score 3):

Parenting is done in **edit** mode where you setup the armature.

`arm.pose.bones` already indicates it is related to posing bones.

Try:

```
arm.data.edit_bones['yourBone'].parent = arm.data.edit_bones['parentBone']
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I didn't get that edit_bones was a collection, I thought it was a method and didn't look into it deep enough, so thanks.